# springboot jdbctemplate string concat failing with error "Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 2"

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, stringbuilder, jdbctemplate

I am using Stringbuilder to concatenate the not null fields for select statement. But its failing with code 
"SQL state [99999]; error code [17041]; Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 2; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 2"

I tried to print the used columns, they are printing fine. Please check and let me know where I am making the mistake.

```js
 public List<Dbinv> listdbbysearch(String database, String server, String node, String dc , String env, String instancename ) {
 
  StringBuilder sqlstmt = new StringBuilder ("select *  from dbinv where ");
  StringBuilder tempval = new StringBuilder ("");

    if ( database !=null) {
    sqlstmt.append ( " database = ?");
    tempval.append ("database");
    }

    if ( server !=null) {
    sqlstmt.append ( " and server =?");
    tempval.append(", server");
    }

    if ( node != null) {
    sqlstmt.append ( " and node =?");
    tempval.append(", node");
    }

    if ( dc != null) {
    sqlstmt.append ( " and dc =?");
    tempval.append(", dc");
    }

    if ( env != null) {
    sqlstmt.append ( " and env =?");
    tempval.append(", env");
    }

    if ( instancename != null) {
    sqlstmt.append ( " and instancename =?");
    tempval.append(", instancename");
    }


    System.out.println(sqlstmt);
    System.out.println(tempval);
  

        
   String query = "Select * from dbinv where ( database = ? or database=null) AND (server = ?) AND ( node = ?) AND (dc = ?) AND (env = ?) AND (instancename = ?)" ;
  List<Dbinv> dbinvs = template.query(sqlstmt.toString(),new Object[]{tempval.toString()},new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(Dbinv.class));

        return dbinvs;

  
          }



}
```

Please note when I hard code the same parameters for test case its working without any errors

Also can anyone suggest option where I can skip using "new Object[]" in my query section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JpaRepository option in springboot, solved my problem, I was able to create custom findby option based on my requirement.